# Import Git repository with submodules into a Subversion repository

Tags: svn, git, import, git-submodules, svn-externals

What is the best approach for importing a Git project with submodules into a Subversion repository?

Not sure if it matters, but the submodules are pointing to the Kohana core and module repositories on github. It would be nice if I could reference these external repositories in Subversion, but it's definitely not a requirement.

Thanks,
Mike

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To import git to svn:

- Create a svn repo, in the standard format that you want imported into.
- Associate your git repo with the svn one:

  ```
  git svn clone https://svn.com/new_svn_repo --stdlayout
  ```
- Checkout the trunck and merge the master

  ```
  git checkout trunk
  git merge master
  ```
- Send the objects to the svn

  ```
  git svn dcommit
  ```
- Done!

I don't think there is a simple way to include submodules within this. You should probably manually add the svn repos `svn externals`

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to import the repository using [SubGit](http://subgit.com). Look at this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10014054/git-2-svn-migration/10564836#10564836) for instructions. Though it doesn't support submodules so far, I know no other tool that does. But it fits migration purposes better.